# Checkbox Control Error in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

Checkbox control is always false till i check the checkbox in gridview;

```
CheckBox grouped = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
```

aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('id')%>">
</asp:Label> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('news_category')%>" </asp:Label> 
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: In which grid event you tried this? share your aspx as well as cs code

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('id')%>"></asp:Label>                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# bind('news_category') %>" ></asp:Label>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />                           
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />

Comment: What is the ERROR? Can you please provide ALL your ASPX code? Can I see your GridView code?

Comment: Please clarify "false", do you mean the Checked property value? Or is the control null?